# gdk_pixbuf_composite usage

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

I have two png images First one with Width1 2247 Height1 190 and second one with Width2 155 Height2 36. I wan't the second image(src) to be placed in the center of first image(dest). I created pixel buf of both and used gdk_pixbuf_composite as follows.

```
gdk_pixbuf_composite( srcpixbuf, dstpixbuf, 1000, 100, width2, height2, 0, 0, 1, 1, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR, 255);
```

I get a hazy window of width2 and height2 on the first image.

If I replace width2 and height2 with 1.0 then I don't get the srcimage on the dstimage. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

gdk_pixbuf_composite( srcpixbuf, dstpixbuf, 1000, 100, width2, height2, 1000, 100, 1, 1, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR, 255);

This solved. Wrongly understood the offset parameter. Basically an intermediate scaled image is created and only the part represented by the dest wid, height is composited. So in my case we need to move the entire unscaled image to the destination offset which is done by the offset parameter.